# Squeezing the ball between two feet and hopping across the field

Tags: rules, football

On occasion you see sometimes players try this tactic where they squeeze the ball between two feet and hop across the goal line in an attempt to score. This is usually kids learning the game or adults goofing around.

Is this legal or must a ball be kicked across the line to count as a goal?

Answer (score 11):

This is completely legal, provided it is done in a manner in which it is still possible to safely challenge for the ball or there are no opponents nearby.

[FIFA Laws of the Game, 2013/14](http://www.fifa.com/mm/document/footballdevelopment/refereeing/81/42/36/log2013en%5fneutral.pdf), p. 121:

> Playing in a dangerous manner is defined as any action that, while
>   trying to play the ball, threatens injury to someone (including the player
>   himself). It is committed with an opponent nearby and prevents the opponent
>   from playing the ball for fear of injury.

If the referee decides that the action by the player makes it dangerous for opponents to challenge for the ball, an indirect free kick is awarded to the opposing team.

If this goes further, and playing the ball moves from being unsafe to an impossibility (for an unreasonable amount of time), a player is cautioned for unsporting behaviour. Note that there is no requirement here for opponents to be nearby.

This is no longer contained in the present text of the Laws, but was last seen in the [2006 FIFA Q&A to the Laws of The Game](http://www.arbitrosdefutbol.com.ar/preguntas_y_respuestas_06_eng.pdf), p.30:

> *A player intentionally lies on the ball for an unreasonable length of
>   time. What action does the referee take?*
>
> He stops play, cautions the player for unsporting behaviour and restarts
>   play with an indirect free kick.

In the [current (2013/14) laws](http://www.fifa.com/mm/document/footballdevelopment/refereeing/81/42/36/log2013en%5fneutral.pdf), this roughly corresponds to the following on p. 123:

> There are different circumstances when a player must be cautioned for
>   unsporting behaviour, e.g. if a player:
>
> ...
>
> - acts in a manner which shows a lack of respect for the game
>
> ...

The restart is once again an indirect free kick.

Thanks to *posdef*, [here is a clip of Cuauhtémoc Blanco using this technique](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5SB-L8jpbs).

Answer (score 2):

A player is not allowed to control the ball (so that it can't move freely) at any time, which would include across the goal line.  Exceptions would be the goalkeeper, or during a throw in.

Comment: And to answer the other part, it doesn't have to be kicked - it can be headed, struck with the body, leg, etc.

Comment: Hmmm... I read through the FIFA laws of the game, and couldn't find a clear prohibition. But it would probably fall under dangerous play. Same for sitting on a ball in play, or lying on top of it.

Comment: You could probably call a foul for impeding as well, although both of those would end up with an indirect free kick for the opposition. Of course, if you managed to **really** do something special it could count as a misconduct for unsporting behavior, but I really doubt that'd ever come up.

Comment: I haven't seen this in the rules either.  Do you have a reference?  Players trap the ball all the time and I've never seen anyone called for it.

Comment: Next time I'm playing, I'll try this hopping technique and see if my goal is allowed to stand!

Comment: Where is this written in the laws?

Comment: Well this answer is not entirely correct, see the Blanco dribble (aka the bunny hop) from WC'98 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5SB-L8jpbs)

Comment: @posdef I was looking for this example for my answer for ages! Thank you! I couldn't put together the right web search, nor could I remember the player who did it.

Comment: @studro you are welcome :) It was not easy to try and remember Senor Blanco, especially with that amazing first name of his :)